# Simulating the randIntNoRep( command on the TI 83

Tags: random, ti-basic

The `randIntNoRep(` command has been released for the TI-84+/SE calculator on OS 2.53MP and above.

The command is used when you need to create a list of numbers in random order in which no integer is repeated.  It is very useful for shuffling a sequence of any numbers.  How can I implement this functionality on an earlier version (OS or device-wise)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating a list of random numbers, and using it to sequence a second list of the numbers that you want randomized.

For example, randomizing a 52 card deck and saving it as a list can be done easily with `randIntNoRep(` :

```
:randIntNoRep(0,51→L₁
```

This can be simulated using the following code:

```
:rand(52→L₂
:seq(X,X,0,51→L₁
:SortA(L₂,L₁
```

`L₂` is set to contain a set of 52 random values.  `L₁` is set to contain the numbers that will be randomized.  By sequencing the lists in ascending order, the same method can be achieved as using `randIntNoRep(`.

Comment: The TI-nspire also lacks the `randIntNoRep` function, and it can be reproduced by the above function, or with `randSamp(seq(x,x,1,52),52)', which is just a simplified version of the above.

Answer (score 0):

You can randomize a list by swapping its elements, like this.

```
:For(F,1,dim(L1))
:    iPart(dim(L1)rand+1)->R
:    L1(R)->T
:    L1(F)->L1(R)
:    T->L1(F)
:End
```

This randomize L1, assuming L1 has all the elements you want it to.